# Instanced rendering to texture array

Tags: webgl

Is it possible to render to multiple textures (i.e. cube map faces, or cascaded SMs) with one draw call? I can bind a texture slice (or a cubemap face) to framebuffer, but that doesn't seem to let me render to more than one slice per call.

I can't use geometry shaders as they aren't supported in webgl, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WebGL? No. Desktop GL and OpenGL ES can use layered framebuffers to render to faces of a cubemap or layers of an array texture. But not WebGL 1.0 or 2.0.

You can of course bind different slices to the same framebuffer as distinct attachments, but each fragment you render goes to *all* of those slices. You can use write masks to turn off writing to specific framebuffers, but not within a draw call. So that's probably not what you want.

It certainly isn't going to help with shadow maps.

Comment: @gman: If by "PoC" you're referring to your code, I explained the difference. In your code, you're rendering to *all* of the layers all of the time. That is, you don't get to pick and choose within a draw call which layers get which triangles. I interpreted the OPs question to be about the latter, since generally speaking, it's kind of pointless to render the same geometry to all of the faces of a cubemap. And it's certainly useless for cascaded shadow maps.

Comment: Oh well, why can't we have nice things? :(